# JavaFX progress bar changes from a seperate function

Tags: java, javafx, progress-bar

I have a JavaFX program that is essentially a button that fires off a function within the same class as `main` and `start`. I'm trying to create a very basic, simple progress bar that lets the user know when the function is completed.

I fire off the function like so, where `foo` is my button and `bar` is my function that I also pass a numeric value to:

`foo.setOnAction(e -> bar("555"));`

How do I pass a value like `progress` to and from the `start` function containing the button and progress bar and the `foo` function so my user can know when `bar` has finished running?

Answer (score 1):

Use the class inside `javafx.property`and bind two properties together.

In the JavaDoc, `ProgressIndictor` and `ProgressBar` has [progressProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ProgressIndicator.html#progressProperty--), which is an instance of `DoubleProperty`.
`Property` class has a [bind](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/Property.html#bind-javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue-) method, which you can bind it to another `ObservableValue` or `Property`.